# How to set up basic Chartist.js chart

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, charts, chartist.js

I feel lost, I read the getting started for Chartist.js and it seems very straight forward but I can't get any charts to show up.

I made a rails app and got the welcome page displaying text, I linked the css and javascript files, but Im not exactly sure how to get it to display. I made a new js file, added the data they have in the documentation and linked it to the main HTML page but nothing shows up?

Comment: could you show us your code to can help you better

Comment: Did you load the `chartist-rails` gem? Or simply the `*.js` files provided?

Comment: Hey guys here is my github repository: https://github.com/zachsergeant/Analytics If you could figure out whats wrong from looking at that it would be a great help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in https://github.com/zachsergeant/Analytics/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb you're loading chartist right before your body closes. Probably your code that generates charts is loaded somewhere within the yield of the layout template. I guess Chartist is not defined at that point. You should follow a better asynchronous script loading mechanism or simply defer the execution of your scripts using the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Draw charts here
  });
</script>
```